# how to link a web page for playing a video created using html5 and google app engine with a python code that detects smile?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I have created a web page (that has a video embeded in it) using google app engine and html5.
There is a python code for detecing smile.what should I do to invoke the python code when the play button is clicked (i.e.)when the video starts to play automatically the viewers face should be detected...
     The app engine code is given below....

```
    import webapp2

    class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
     self.response.out.write("""<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>          
            <body>  
            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="/video/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="/video/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
             Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
            </body>
            </html>""")

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])
```

The app.yaml file is....

```
    application: video
    version: 1
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true

    handlers:
    - url: /video
     static_dir: video

    - url: /.*
    script: video.app

    - url: /(.*\.mp4)
    static_files: video/\1
    mime_type: video/mp4
    upload: video/(.*\.mp4)

    - url: /(.*\.ogg)
    static_files: video/\1
    mime_type: video/ogg
    upload: video/(.*\.ogv)
```

The python code for smile detection is....

```
    import cv

    HAAR_CASCADE_PATH = "haarcascade_smile.xml"

    CAMERA_INDEX = 0

    def detect_faces(image):
             faces = []
             detected = cv.HaarDetectObjects(image, cascade, storage, 1.1,99,0,(40,40))
    if detected:
           for (x,y,w,h),n in detected:
                    faces.append((x,y,w,h))
           return faces

    if __name__ == "__main__":
            cv.NamedWindow("Video", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

            capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(CAMERA_INDEX)
            storage = cv.CreateMemStorage()
            cascade = cv.Load(HAAR_CASCADE_PATH)

            faces = []

            i = 0
            c = -1
            while (c == -1):
                 image = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

                 #Only run the Detection algorithm every 5 frames to improve performance
                 if i%5==0:
                       faces = detect_faces(image)

                 for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                       cv.Rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255)

                 cv.ShowImage("Video", image)   
                 i += 1
                 c = cv.WaitKey(10)
```

Comment: You need to record from the users camera via HTML5 (or Flash) send the videostream to you server and analyse it there. (You do the same with JavaScript and just send the result.)

Comment: can you make it a bit more clear please...

Comment: Thehippo explains it very clear. You need to first post your code not your idea, then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't.

The video will be streamed to the client browser and played on the client browser.
Since it's running in the browser, you'll need to run your smile detection code in the browser.  It'll have to by javascript instead of python.